# jquery-ui-map setting the geolocation zoom level

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

I am using jquery-ui-map and need to set the zoom level on the users location.
Currently it locates the user and then zooms in completely, but I want it to be zoomed out further.
My javascript skills are lacking and I have searched for the answer and tried a bunch of things but nothing seems to work. Here is the code...

```
jQuery('#map_canvas').gmap({'center': '-23.7002104, 133.8806114','zoom': 3 }).bind('init', function() { 
    jQuery('#map_canvas').gmap('getCurrentPosition', function(position, status) {
    if ( status === 'OK' ) {
    var clientPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
        jQuery.getJSON( 'http://publicaccessgolf.com.au/mapdata/', function(data) { 
            jQuery.each( data.course, function(i, course) {
                jQuery('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', { 
                    'position': new google.maps.LatLng(course.latitude, course.longitude),      
                }).click(function() {
                    jQuery('#map_canvas').gmap('openInfoWindow', { 'content': '<div align="left"><p style="color:#000000;"><a href="http://publicaccessgolf.com.au/' + course.slug + '" >' + course.name + '</a><br />' + course.address + '<br />' + course.contact + '</p></div>' }, this);
                });
            });
        });
        jQuery('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', {'position': clientPosition, 'zoom': 3});

    }
    });     
});
```

Okay I worked it out, correct code is below. Used maxZoom instead of zoom

```
jQuery('#map_canvas').gmap({'center': '-23.7002104, 133.8806114','maxZoom': 11}).bind('init', function() { 
    jQuery('#map_canvas').gmap('getCurrentPosition', function(position, status) {
    if ( status === 'OK' ) {
    var clientPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
        jQuery.getJSON( 'http://publicaccessgolf.com.au/mapdata/', function(data) { 
            jQuery.each( data.course, function(i, course) {
                jQuery('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', { 
                    'position': new google.maps.LatLng(course.latitude, course.longitude),      
                }).click(function() {
                    jQuery('#map_canvas').gmap('openInfoWindow', { 'content': '<div align="left"><p style="color:#000000;"><a href="http://publicaccessgolf.com.au/' + course.slug + '" >' + course.name + '</a><br />' + course.address + '<br />' + course.contact + '</p></div>' }, this);
                });
            });
        });
        jQuery('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', {'position': clientPosition, 'bounds':true});

    }
    });     
});
```

Comment: `jQuery('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', {'position': clientPosition, 'zoom': 3});` is this line your issue?

Comment: Well I thought that setting the zoom level here would work but it doesn't. I tried 'bounds':true but that zooms it in fully

Comment: have you tried the suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Once i had an issue like this, then i just read the api docs and found a way this one and this worked for me, you can replace this line:

```
jQuery('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', {'position': clientPosition, 'zoom': 3});
```

with this:

```
 jQuery('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', {'position': clientPosition});
 jQuery('#map_canvas').gmap('option','zoom',3);
 jQuery('#map_canvas').gmap('option','center',new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude));
```

try this and see if this helps you.